# I'm trying to understand how substring call is working in this code?

Tags: java, substring, indexof

I know how substring works, but I was trying to understand how it works in the code below. The goal was to find the longest common prefix in an array of strings. The string input was {flower, flow, fleece}. It looks like substring is just taking the entire word of flower, when it's not 0, each time, as 0 to length-1 is going to give the entire word.

```
 public String longestCommonPrefix(String[] strs) {
    if (strs.length == 0) return "";
    String prefix = strs[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < strs.length; i++)
        while (strs[i].indexOf(prefix) != 0) {
            prefix = prefix.substring(0, prefix.length() - 1);
            if (prefix.isEmpty()) return "";
        }        
    return prefix;
}
```

The output is fl. I'm just trying to understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst this isn't directly what you are asking about, it is worth mentioning that using `indexOf` and `substring` is not a good way to approach this.

`strs[i].indexOf(prefix) != 0` is an inefficient way to check if a string starts with something. This is because if it finds the string doesn't start with `prefix`, it keeps on searching for an occurrence at other positions - and it doesn't matter if it appears there.

A more efficient check would be `!strs[i].startsWith(prefix)`: as soon as it finds the string doesn't start with the prefix, it stops.

Then, using `substring` to chop a character off the end of the string is inefficient too: each time it chops off one character, it creates a new string, and then you check again; but you might have to chop off *lots* of individual characters before you find a matching prefix.

You can avoid the "creating objects" bit of this, by using `strs[i].regionMatches(0, prefix, 0, someLength)`, where `someLength` is an int that starts off at `prefix.length()`, and you decrement until `regionMatches` returns true. But this is still inefficient in that you are decrementing it one at a time.

It's easier if you do it the other way: start with `someLength` at zero, and *increment* it until either:

- It equals the length of `prefix`: `someLength >= prefix.length()`
- It equals the length of `strs[i]`: `someLength >= strs[i].length()`
- The corresponding chars at that position don't match: `prefix.charAt(someLength) != strs[i].charAt(someLength)`

This is basically what `startsWith` does, but by doing it "yourself", you find out the position where the strings differ.

Then, use `prefix = prefix.substring(0, someLength);` to chop it in one go. Or don't chop it at all: you can simply store the length of the common prefix, and do the substring once, at the end.

The code would look something like:

```
public String longestCommonPrefix(String[] strs) {
    if (strs.length == 0) return "";
    int prefixLength = strs[0].length();
    for (int i = 1; i < strs.length; i++) {
        int s = 0;
        while (s < prefixLength
            && s < strs[i].length()
            && strs[0].charAt(s) == strs[i].charAt(s)) {
          ++s;
        }
        prefixLength = s;
    }
    return strs[0].substring(0, prefixLength);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> 0 to length-1 is going to give the entire word

No, it returns the word except the last char.
From: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)

> public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
>  Returns a
>   new string that is a substring of this string.  
> The substring
>   begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at
>   index endIndex - 1.

So what the code does is trims the last char at each iteration with this line:

```
prefix = prefix.substring(0, prefix.length() - 1);
```

until it finds a common prefix.

Comment: I’m also confused on the while condition? If it’s iterating until 0 is reached, it’s iterating until the beginning of the word? When something isn’t found, indexOf returns negative 1?

Comment: The meaning of `indexOf(prefix) != 0` is that the prefix must start at the 1st char (index=0) of the word that it is compared to. So the loop goes on by trimming the last char until the prefix is the same as the start of the word, meaning its starting position is 0.

Answer (score 1):

the endIndex in substring() is exclusive. So, what the code does is remove the last character from the prefix variable.

```
String hello = "hello";
System.out.println(hello.substring(0,hello.length));
// hello
System.out.println(hello.substring(0,hello.length - 1));
// hell
```